# Genomic coordinates of predicted binding pocket

Tags: proteins, genomics, drugs

I would like to know the genomic coordinates of a proteins ligand-binding pocket.  For example, on [this PDB page](http://www.rcsb.org/structure/1OG5) you can see that there is xray crystallography data for how CYP2C9 interacts with two ligands. I would like to know which amino acids form the space on the protein that binds the ligands, then translate (de-translate?) that back to the nucleotide sequence. Is anyone familiar with either a database that has this information or how to extract the ligand interaction data from the PDB files?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there is a tool that does this beautifully.  I used the `proteinToGenome` function from the [ensembldb](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ensembldb/inst/doc/coordinate-mapping.html#5_mapping_protein_coordinates_to_the_genome) package.

The code looks like this:

```
# Define the Ensemble database object for the 
edbX <- filter(EnsDb.Hsapiens.v75, filter = ~ seq_name == "X") 
# Set the first and last amino acid you want to convert and the ensembl protein id
GAGE10_prt <- IRanges(start = 5, end = 9, names = "ENSP00000385415")
# Perform the conversion.  GAGE10_prt is an object that has the coordinates
GAGE10_prt <- proteinToGenome(GAGE10_prt, edbX)
```

Answer (score 1):

That PDB page includes a publication reference and abstract, containing the following text:

> Mammalian CYP450s recognize and metabolize diverse xenobiotics such as
> drug molecules, environmental compounds and pollutants.
>
> ...
>
> Here we describe the crystal structure of a human CYP450, CYP2C9, both unliganded and in complex with the anti-coagulant drug warfarin.

[Here's](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/gdv/browser/?context=genome&acc=GCF_000001405.38) the genomic context for CYP2C9, with Ensembl page [here](https://asia.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Gene/Summary?g=ENSG00000138109).

The binding pocket images from the paper [here](https://media.springernature.com/m685/nature-assets/nature/journal/v424/n6947/images/nature01862-f1.2.jpg) and [here](https://media.springernature.com/m685/nature-assets/nature/journal/v424/n6947/images/nature01862-f2.2.jpg) indicate that the following amino acids are potentially involved in the interaction:

- Arg97
- Phe100
- Ala103
- Val113
- Phe114
- Asn217
- Pro367
- Phe476

Using the filtering from the [UCSC table browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables) (genome: Human; group: Genes & Gene Predictions; Basic table; Region: genome; Identifiers: CYP2C9; Output format: CDS fasta alignment), I get the following amino acid sequences respectively for the exons in CYP2C9. I have added in the protein reference range to the end, with the help of the R `cumsum` function applied to the region lengths, `cumsum(c(56,54,50,54,59,47,63,47,61))`:

```
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_1_9 56 0 0 chr10:94938683-94938850+ [1-56]
MDSLVVLVLCLSCLLLLSLWRQSSGRGKLPPGPTPLPVIGNILQIGIKDISKSLTN
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_2_9 54 0 1 chr10:94941858-94942020+ [57-110]
LSKVYGPVFTLYFGLKPIVVLHGYEAVKEALIDLGEEFSGRGIFPLAERANRGF
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_3_9 50 1 1 chr10:94942192-94942341+ [111-160]
GIVFSNGKKWKEIRRFSLMTLRNFGMGKRSIEDRVQEEARCLVEELRKTK
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_4_9 54 1 0 chr10:94947779-94947939+ [161-214]
ASPCDPTFILGCAPCNVICSIIFHKRFDYKDQQFLNLMEKLNENIKILSSPWIQ
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_5_9 59 0 0 chr10:94949108-94949284+ [215-273]
ICNNFSPIIDYFPGTHNKLLKNVAFMKSYILEKVKEHQESMDMNNPQDFIDCFLMKMEK
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_6_9 47 0 1 chr10:94972104-94972245+ [274-320]
EKHNQPSEFTIESLENTAVDLFGAGTETTSTTLRYALLLLLKHPEVT
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_7_9 63 1 0 chr10:94981183-94981370+ [321-383]
AKVQEEIERVIGRNRSPCMQDRSHMPYTDAVVHEVQRYIDLLPTSLPHAVTCDIKFRNYLIPK
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_8_9 47 0 1 chr10:94986033-94986174+ [384-430]
GTTILISLTSVLHDNKEFPNPEMFDPHHFLDEGGNFKKSKYFMPFSA
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_9_9 61 1 0 chr10:94988847-94989028+ [431-491]
GKRICVGEALAGMELFLFLTSILQNFNLKSLVDPKNLDTTPVVNGFASVPPFYQLCFIPVZ
```

And these nucleic acid sequences:

```
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_1_9 168 0 0 chr10:94938683-94938850+
ATGGATTCTCTTGTGGTCCTTGTGCTCTGTCTCTCATGTTTGCTTCTCCTTTCACTCTGGAGACAGAGCTCTGGGAGAGGAAAACTCCCTCCTGGCCCCACTCCTCTCCCAGTGATTGGAAATATCCTACAGATAGGTATTAAGGACATCAGCAAATCCTTAACCAAT
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_2_9 163 0 1 chr10:94941858-94942020+
CTCTCAAAGGTCTATGGCCCTGTGTTCACTCTGTATTTTGGCCTGAAACCCATAGTGGTGCTGCATGGATATGAAGCAGTGAAGGAAGCCCTGATTGATCTTGGAGAGGAGTTTTCTGGAAGAGGCATTTTCCCACTGGCTGAAAGAGCTAACAGAGGATTTG
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_3_9 150 1 1 chr10:94942192-94942341+
GAATTGTTTTCAGCAATGGAAAGAAATGGAAGGAGATCCGGCGTTTCTCCCTCATGACGCTGCGGAATTTTGGGATGGGGAAGAGGAGCATTGAGGACCGTGTTCAAGAGGAAGCCCGCTGCCTTGTGGAGGAGTTGAGAAAAACCAAGG
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_4_9 161 1 0 chr10:94947779-94947939+
CCTCACCCTGTGATCCCACTTTCATCCTGGGCTGTGCTCCCTGCAATGTGATCTGCTCCATTATTTTCCATAAACGTTTTGATTATAAAGATCAGCAATTTCTTAACTTAATGGAAAAGTTGAATGAAAACATCAAGATTTTGAGCAGCCCCTGGATCCAG
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_5_9 177 0 0 chr10:94949108-94949284+
ATCTGCAATAATTTTTCTCCTATCATTGATTACTTCCCGGGAACTCACAACAAATTACTTAAAAACGTTGCTTTTATGAAAAGTTATATTTTGGAAAAAGTAAAAGAACACCAAGAATCAATGGACATGAACAACCCTCAGGACTTTATTGATTGCTTCCTGATGAAAATGGAGAAG
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_6_9 142 0 1 chr10:94972104-94972245+
GAAAAGCACAACCAACCATCTGAATTTACTATTGAAAGCTTGGAAAACACTGCAGTTGACTTGTTTGGAGCTGGGACAGAGACGACAAGCACAACCCTGAGATATGCTCTCCTTCTCCTGCTGAAGCACCCAGAGGTCACAG
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_7_9 188 1 0 chr10:94981183-94981370+
CTAAAGTCCAGGAAGAGATTGAACGTGTGATTGGCAGAAACCGGAGCCCCTGCATGCAAGACAGGAGCCACATGCCCTACACAGATGCTGTGGTGCACGAGGTCCAGAGATACATTGACCTTCTCCCCACCAGCCTGCCCCATGCAGTGACCTGTGACATTAAATTCAGAAACTATCTCATTCCCAAG
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_8_9 142 0 1 chr10:94986033-94986174+
GGCACAACCATATTAATTTCCCTGACTTCTGTGCTACATGACAACAAAGAATTTCCCAACCCAGAGATGTTTGACCCTCATCACTTTCTGGATGAAGGTGGCAATTTTAAGAAAAGTAAATACTTCATGCCTTTCTCAGCAG
>ENST00000260682.7_hg38_9_9 182 1 0 chr10:94988847-94989028+
GAAAACGGATTTGTGTGGGAGAAGCCCTGGCCGGCATGGAGCTGTTTTTATTCCTGACCTCCATTTTACAGAACTTTAACCTGAAATCTCTGGTTGACCCAAAGAACCTTGACACCACTCCAGTTGTCAATGGATTTGCCTCTGTGCCGCCCTTCTACCAGCTGTGCTTCATTCCTGTCTGA
```

Associating the pocket protein amino acid numbers in exons 2,3,5,7,9 with genomic sequence using these FASTA sequences is left as an exercise for the reader.